# Detect TimeoutException on server side WCF

Tags: wcf, transactions, timeoutexception

I have a WCF service that has some operations that may take long...
  The client receives a TimeoutException, but the server continues executing after the long operation.

Server:

```
public void doSomeWork(TransmissionObject o) {
    doDBOperation1(o); // 
    doDBOperation2(o); // may result in TimeoutException on client
    doDBOperation3(o); // it continues doing DB operations. The client is unaware!
}
```

Client:

```
ServiceReference.IServiceClient cli = new ServiceReference.IServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IService","http://localhost:3237/Test/service.svc");
int size = 1000;
Boolean done = false;
TransmissionObject o = null;

while(!done) {
   o = createTransmissionObject(size);
   try {
      cli.doSomeWork(o);
      done = true; 
   }catch(TimeoutException ex) {
      // We want to reduce the size of the object, and try again
      size--;
      // the DB operations in server succeed, but the client doesn't know
      // this makes errors.
   }catch(Exception ex) { ... }
}
```

Since the server is performing some DB operations, I need to detect the timeout on the server side to be able to rollback the DB operations.

I tried to use Transactions with [TransactionFlow], TransactionScope, etc, on the client side, but the DB operations on the server are using Stored Procedures that are NESTED!!, therefore I cannot use distributed transactions. (I receive an SqlException saying: Cannot Use SAVE TRANSACTION Within A Distributed Transaction.). If I use simple SPs (that are not nested), then the solution with the transactions works fine.

My Question:
  How can I detect the TimeoutException, but on the server side? I guess is something related to the proxy status... or probably some Events that can be captured by the server.
  I'm not sure if handling the transaction on the server side is the correct solution.. 
  Is there a pattern to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for an operation to time out, you may consider using asynchronous operations, as in this blog post: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/18/async-operations-in-wcf-event-based-model/

The idea is that you precisely expect an operation to take some time. The server will signal to the client when the job is finished.